# Is there a way to display a Lotus Notes document link in an exchange email?

Tags: lotus-notes

We have moved to Exchange and with all of our Notes databases, we are trying to find a way of adding a link to a document without using a third party app that converts the link currently.  All of my coding within the Notes app is done in LotusScript.

Thank you.
Jean

Comment: Have you tried sending notes::// URLs?

Comment: will check into that .... thank you